# Excel Conditional Formatting When Not Between Two Numbers AND Not Zero

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I'm trying to format a columns of cells if they are not between a range of numbers AND not equal to zero.  I want to compare the same row between column H and column O.  I can get either of the two, but not the combined argument. Look at the first attached picture to see the not between conditional formatting working:

[[image: conditional formatting working].

I try this code to no avail:

```
=AND($O$7 <> 0, H7*(1-$H$1)<$O$7, H7*(1+$H$1)>$O$7)
```

It doesn't format anything

[image: anything].

If I correct the range, as it should have started at row 8, I get the following:

```
=AND(O8 <> 0, H8*(1-$H$1)<O8, H8*(1+$H$1)>O8)
```

[image: Incorrect highlighting]

Comment: It would help if the formula was in range.

Comment: =AND($O$8 <> 0, H8*(1-$H$1)<$O$8, H8*(1+$H$1)>$O$8)

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59363477/edit) instead of adding information in comments. That said, are you sure you need absolute coordinates for all those cells?

Comment: I'm looking to have the same row compared between column O and column H for a range of rows (8-150).  The range of rows is set in the conditional formatting window.